# Determination of SMS Gateway to use for phone numbers?

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms

I'd like to explore the usage of email-to-SMS services such as sending an email to: `some_number@vtext.com`.  Obviously it's not hard to do this, however the trick is in obtaining a user's carrier.

Ideally one could access a database to retrieve the carrier, however I am doubtful that that's possible.

Secondly, an SMTP like service that would essentially make a query to some_number and then all the various carriers to get a positive or negative reply as to whether the number exists with that carrier, would be great... but again, I'm not sure if that is possible.  If it were, one could just go down the list and when a carrier email SMTP gateway replies with a message that this number exists, then we're probably good... unless it was recently at another carrier.

The third and least optimum solution it seems is to have a user select the carrier themselves.  In order to do this, it would be best to have a database of various carriers that is up-to-date (obviously). Is there such a database or support library for this?

**What approach of these three (or am I missing another recommended solution?) is doable or facilitated by some support library so as to remove some of the maintenance and logic considerations from implementation?**

The preferred answer would be Ruby specific, however I'm open to other libs from other languages as well in order to understand the landscape better.

Comment: You really should use something like Twilio. Option one isn't available to you, option two will get you blocked very quickly, and option three will get you blocked if you do much volume.

Comment: Already using Twilio, however at this point it's necessary for me to also have this as another option.  Option probably wouldn't get blocked if you don't query every time; just on user registration so it's a once then and then perhaps maintenance / check every 60 days or so.